# What facility does java provide for getting input from the command line for the executeUpdate() method in SQL

Tags: java, sql

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter Staff Name: ");
String staffName = input.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter Department Name: ");
String department =Input.nextLine();

stmt.executeUpdate("insert into staff (StaffName,department) " + "values " +  
staffName,department);
```

This gives me an error and asks me to check the SQL manual.Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, since it happened. Strings must be enclosed in quotes in SQL:

```
insert into foo (bar, baz) values ('hello', 'world');
```

Learn to use [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) instead of string concatenations, to make your queries work, and not be subject to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("insert into staff (StaffName, department) values (?, ?)");
stmt.setString(1, staffName);
stmt.setString(2, department);
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Using the above, you don't need to mess with quotes nor escape them inside the strings.

Comment: Thanks mate.Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessarily the user input being formatted incorrectly.  The INSERT into should be formatted like:

```
INSERT INTO <table_name>
VALUES (<1>, <2>, ... <n>);
```

To format your SQL query correctly, you could try:

```
String sql = "INSTERT INTO STAFF (StaffName, department) VALUES (\'" + 
  staffName + "\', \'" + department + "\');";
```

Comment: Thanks for your time,unfortunately your suggestion compiles but does not add the record to the table.